# Loading dependent DLLs from another folder(C++\CLI\C#)

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, dll

Ok my current enviroment is like this;

1. Native App1.exe in **MyFirstLocation**\App1.exe
2. MyDllFirst.dll in  **MyAnotherLocation**\MyDllFirst.dll (C++\CLI)
3. MyDllSecond.dll in **MyAnotherLocation**\MyDllSecond.dll (C# dll)

App1.exe ---Loads-->MyDllFirst.dll---Loads-->MyDllSecond.dll

App1.exe Loads MyDllFirst.dll with SetDllDirectory and LoadLibrary and etc..
But MyDllFirst.dll cannot load MyDllSecond.dll

if I do something like this instead of third item, then it works;

3. MyDllSecond.dll in **MyFirstLocation**\MyDllSecond.dll (C# dll)

I think because dll loading context is in exe's directory Second dll is not found.

My questions are;

What are my options to link MyDllFirst and MyDllSecond for runtime and load time linking?

Is there any way to link these two dlls from the App1.exe itself?

PS: I do not prefer to use AssemblyResolve functionality in MyDllFirst to find the directory of the MyDllSecond and load it from there

Hopefully I made my self clear any help is appreciated

Comment: Hmya, the CLR has no hope of finding that DLL.  The best way to execute managed code from a native program is by using the hosting api, you get to configure the primary appdomain just the way you want it.  You can limp along by implementing the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event in your C++/CLI code.  Or a .config file with the same name as the native .exe to configure the probing path.  Or just not giving the CLR a hard time, by far the simplest solution of course.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Hans, What do you mean exactly by hosting api?

Comment: Just google "clr hosting api"